# Function property of $o$

Tags: special-functions, taylor-expansion

I have a doubt regarding $o$-function. Could we write $o(\|\theta h)\|)=\theta \ o(\|h\|)$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $f\mathcal o(g) = \mathcal o(fg)$? If so, yes.

Comment: Actually, I was talking about constant, $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ (sorry I did not mention it). So, I think what you suggested, if that is true, then it is also true for constant. Please, let me know whether I am correct or not. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: It is also true that $k\mathcal o(f) = \mathcal o(kf) = \mathcal o(f)$, for $k \in \mathbb R$. However I don't know what you mean by $\|h\|$, so I'm not sure. Actually the $\mathcal o$ I'm talking about is not a special function, but rather a notation. But seeing that you tagged the question with `special-functions` it might be that we are talking about different things.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, I want to use this result to show that,
$$t(\nabla f(x)^T d+o(∥d∥))=t \nabla f(x)^T d+ o(\|td\|), \text{ where } t \in \mathbb{R}, t \geq 0 \text{ and } a,d\in \mathbb{R}^n$$
$$f(x+t) = f(x) +t \nabla f(x)^T d+ o(\|td\|),$$
So if, $f(x) \geq f(x+d), \text{ then } f(x) \geq f(x+td)$